# Horizontally aligning a h3 and h5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap to align my `h3` headings with my `h5` so that they are in line with each other.

**EDIT**
I am trying to use the already available bootstrap and avoid changing the css unless absolutely necessary.

Here is a screen to demonstrate what i mean.
[image]

E.g. First name should line up with address 1, last name with address 2 etc.

here is the code I have.

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <h3>First Name</h3>
      <h3>Last Name</h3>
      <h3>Week.</h3>
      <h3>Code.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <h5>Address 1</h5>
      <h5>Address 2</h5>
      <h5>Address 3</h5>
      <h5>Country</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: might be better wrapped in a `ul` element :)

Comment: Surely having a heading as each line is totally semantically incorrect? but to achieve what you want, just have the line-heights match or the h5 line height equal the h3 font size

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think you hit the nail on the head their, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell no worries, glad to help :)

Comment: I'd argue that *sematically* - **they shouldn't be headings at all**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what headers are for. (semantically incorrect, search engines won't like this)

I suggest to simply use a table for this (it IS tabular data) and use different CSS rules for `td:first-child`  and `td:nth-child(2)` in order to get the different font sizes.

```css
.x {
  width: 100%;
}
.x td {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: light;
}
.x td:first-child {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 60%;
}
.x td:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<table class="x">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Address 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Address 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Week.</td>
    <td>Address 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code.</td>
    <td>Country</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd argue you want `vertical-align:bottom` in there too.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am not 100% sure, but I think the default is `baseline`, which would fit better IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Better not to mess with the h3/h5 heights, and use multiple `row`s instead. E.g. what if one of the texts becomes so long that it wraps? Then you can say bye-bye to your aligned layout. That will never happen if you use multple `row`s:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>First Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h5>Address 1</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Last Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h5>Address 2</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Week.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h5>Address 3</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Code.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <h5>Country</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apart from all this: I agree with the remarks by others that you shouldn't be using h3/h5 in the first place. Headers are intended to define relations between logical units of text, so `<h5>` is the header of a sub-sub section of text inside a chapter of text that is headed by a `<h3>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

set same line-heigt, margins, and padding for h3&h5 in css styles